# save a plot resulting from a function matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, jpeg, ipython

I created a function that takes a range of values from a data set and outputs a plot. For instance:

`my_plot(location_dataset, min_temperature, max_temperature)` will return a plot of precipitation for the range of temperature specified in the function.

Let's say I want to save the plot for the temperature between 60-70F in California. so, I would call my function `my_plot(California, 60, 70)` and will get a plot of precipitation for California when temperatures are between 60 and 70F.

My question is: how do I save a plot that results from calling a function into a jpeg format?

I know of `plt.savefig()` when it is not the result of calling a function but in my case how do I do this?

Thanks!

More details: here is my code (heavily simplified):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_plot(location_dataset, min_temperature, max_temperature):
    condition = (location_dataset['temperature'] > min_temperature) & (dataset['temperature'] <= max_temperature)
    subset = location_dataset[condition] # subset the data based on the temperature range

    x = subset['precipitation'] # takes the precipitation column only
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.show()
```

So then I call this function as follow: `my_plot(California, 60, 70)` and I get my plot for the 60-70 temperature range. how do I save this plot without having the `savefig` inside the function definition (and that is because I need to change the min and max temperature parameters.

Comment: because my plot is the result of a function that I call, does that make sense, or should I edit my original post?

Comment: Share some more code then. What does `my_plot` return? Or, save the plot within the `my_plot` function.

Comment: ok, I edited it. To answer to your question, my_plot returns a plot given the temperature range specified by the `min_temperature` and `mx_temperature` parameters

Comment: It is bad practice to call `pyplot` with in a function, it is better to pass your function an `Axes` object and use the OO interface.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take the reference to the `figure` to some variable, and return it from your function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_plot(location_dataset, min_temperature, max_temperature):
    condition = (location_dataset['temperature'] > min_temperature) & (dataset['temperature'] <= max_temperature)
    subset = location_dataset[condition] # subset the data based on the temperature range

    x = subset['precipitation'] # takes the precipitation column only
    # N.B. referenca taken to fig
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.show()

    return fig
```

When you call this function, you can use the reference for saving the figure:

```
fig = my_plot(...)
fig.savefig("somefile.png")
```

Comment: Did you try to put `fig.save` directly into the function？