# How to save deep super learner graphs?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am trying to run a deep super learning package (https://github.com/levyben/DeepSuperLearner) which gives 2 graphs but does not  show how to save them - from this code is there anything I can add to save the graphs?

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MLP_learner = dcv.GridSearchCV(mlp, parameter_space, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=-1)
    GBM_learner = dcv.GridSearchCV(gbm, param, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=-1)
    LR_learner = dcv.GridSearchCV(logreg, LR_par, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=-1)
    RFC_learner = dcv.GridSearchCV(rfc, param_grid, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=-1)
    SVM_learner =  dcv.GridSearchCV(svm, tuned_parameters, cv=inner_cv, iid=False, n_jobs=-1)
    Keras_learner = GridSearchCV(estimator=keras, param_grid=kerasparams, cv=inner_cv,iid=False, n_jobs=-1)
    Base_learners = {'MultilayerPerceptron':MLP_learner, 'GradientBoostingMachine':GBM_learner, 
        'LogisticRegression':LR_learner,'RandomForest':RF_learner, 'SupportVectorMachine':SVM_learner, 'Keras':Keras_learner}

    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X_res, y_res, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    DSL_learner = DeepSuperLearner(Base_learners)
    DSL_learner.fit(X_train, Y_train,max_iterations=1,sample_weight=None)
    DSL_learner.get_precision_recall(X_test, Y_test, show_graphs=True) 
    y_pred = DSL_learner.predict(X_test)
    y_pred = numpy.argmax(y_pred,axis=1) 
    print("Deep Super Learner Test Accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_pred, Y_test)*100, "%")
```

I assume it's the 'show_graphs=True' giving me the graphs but I need to be able to save these outputs, from reading the documentation in the github they do not give that option to add into the .get_precision_recall()  function. I have been trying to apply matplotlib's savefig() but with no success so far.

I have tried adding:

```
    plot = DSL_learner.get_precision_recall(X_test, Y_test, show_graphs=True)
    plt.show(plot)
    plot.savefig('DeepSuperLearner.png')
```

but this gives the error:
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'savefig'`

Here is the image I get (ran quickly with less models for speed just to show) and that I am trying to save:
[image: graphs]

These are also the same as what is in the example of the github.
Also when I run:

```
  plot = DSL_learner.get_precision_recall(X_test, Y_test, show_graphs=True)
  plt.show(plot)
```

the graph image outputs a 2nd time. I am running this in jupyter lab (however need to be able to save the graphs to run this code elsewhere and still get the graphs)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've editted to show what I've tried, if I try plt.savefig()  only it gives an empty figure - is it possible that this is due to the function giving me 2 graphs? (1 or precision and 1 for recall)

Comment: You may need to edit the source module so that it returns a reference to the plotted figure. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791709/save-a-plot-resulting-from-a-function-matplotlib-python

Comment: This has worked - thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save a plot resulting from a function matplotlib python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791709/save-a-plot-resulting-from-a-function-matplotlib-python)